# Scalar um valor em um determinado intervalo

Tags: java, matemática

O meu professor de programação fez essa pergunta e eu não consegui entender porque tenho que usar uma dessas formulas para escalar a temperatura.E também não consegui identificar qual seria a resposta certa.
Você tem a variável temperatura, a qual vai de -40 para +40. Você deseja mudar a variável corVermelho que vai de 0 a 255 conforme a temperatura vai de -40 para +40. Qual é a resposta correta?

```
a.255*(temp+40)/80
b. 255*(temp-40)/40
c. 255-(temp+40)/80
d. 255*(temp-40)/80
e.255-(temp+40)/40
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A resposta nesse caso seria a alternativa `a.`.

Veja bem, se fizermos uma divisão básica das variações possíveis entre `corVermelha` e `temperatura` temos que a cada variação da `temperatura` varia `255 / 80 = 3.1875` da `corVermelha`.

Sendo assim, para obter o valor de `corVermelha` precisamos saber quanto a `temperatura` variou multiplicado por esse valor. No caso:

`(temp + 40) //Aqui obtemos a variação onde temp é a temperatura atual
 255/80 //O valor da variação de corVermelha
 255/80*(temp + 40) // A resposta a.`

Comment: Agora entendi e faz muito sentido. Excelente explicação!

Answer (score 0):

A ideia é fazer uma proporção entre as duas escalas, sendo estas:

- `0` a `255`
- `-40` a `40`

Repare que as escalas não tem a mesma base, e por isso podemos ajustar somando `40` à escala `-40` a `40` que dá uma escala `0` a `80`.

Com as duas escalas na mesma base divide-se o valor mais alto das duas para dar a proporção:

```
255 / 80 = 3,1875
```

Podemos dizer que a escala `0` a `255` é `3,1875` vezes maior que a escala `0` a `80`. Logo transformar um valor de `0` a `80` para essa escala é apenas multiplicar por `3,1875`.

Mas como os valores vão de `-40` a `40` é preciso primeiro ajustar o valor a esta escala de `0` a `80` somando `40`.

Veja os seguintes exemplos:

- Temperatura  40: `(40+40) * 3,1875 = 255`
- Temperatura  10: `(40+10) * 3,1875 = 158,75`
- Temperatura -23: `(40-23) * 3,1875 = 31,875`
- Temperatura -40: `(40-40) * 3,1875 = 0`

Se reparar nos passos que foram feitos vai ver que corresponde à resposta A, que é a correta.

Comment: Excelente explicação! Deu para entender o passo a passo! Ficou bem claro agora!